# When I apply fonts in my Expo app it shows on web but doesn't applies on android or IOS

Tags: android, react-native

[image]

This Is MY Emulator and my fonts doesn't show here

MY Code is

```
import { StyleSheet, View , Text } from 'react-native';
import Main from './src/Components/MainInput';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Scheme } from './src/Utils/ColorScheme';
import { Spacing } from './src/Utils/Spacing';
import GettingTime from './src/Components/GettingTime';
import { DancingScript_400Regular , useFonts } from '@expo-google-fonts/dancing-script';


export default function App() {
    const [ data, addData ] = useState(null);
    let [ fontsLoaded ] = useFonts({
       DancingScript_400Regular,
      });
   
      if (!fontsLoaded) {
        return null;
      }
      
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {data ? <GettingTime 
            
             givenData={data}
              addData={addData}
               /> : <Main adddata={addData}/>}
               <View style={styles.copy}>
                <Text style={styles.copyText}>This App is Created by &copy; Hayder Ali. All &copy; Copyrights and &trade; Trademarks are reserved</Text>
               </View>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: Scheme.background,
        alignItems: 'center',
        paddingTop: Spacing.xxxxl
    },
    copy:{
        padding:Spacing.md,
        
        
    },
    copyText:{
        color:Scheme.Figures,
        textAlign:"justify",
     fontFamily:"normal"
    }
});
```

Can Anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create assets Folder
2. Create Fonts Folder
3. Paste file in Fonts folder
4. Add Fonts in Fonts folder
5. Create react-native.config.js file
6. Add this code in react-native.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
  assets: ['./src/assets/Fonts'],
};
```

7. Run `npx react-native link` command

Comment: Please add some details in your answer

Comment: I'm sorry I am using EXPO not react native

Answer (score 3):

For one I had to delete a `fontWeight: 'bold'` declaration I had made because that's actually not allowed. Secondly I had to restart my expo server. I tried adding the 'bold' declaration back afterward to test it and it indeed broke it again.

Comment: spent 5 hours looking for this , thank you!